# Eclipse - new android activity showing in manifest but missing under src

Tags: android, eclipse

I created a new blank activity from Eclipse's 'New' menu.

I didn't get any errors, and the activity looks to have been correctly populated in the manifest, however, no java class file has been created.

I get the impression that within Eclipse, the class should have been auto-created and auto-populated with the onCreate and onOptionsItemSelected method templates.

Why didn't Eclipse automatically create the class for me?

Manifest code as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstandroidapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstandroidapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstandroidapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstandroidapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstandroidapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

[image: AndroidManifest.xml Application Nodes showing new activity which is missing under src]

Comment: please show me manifest file xml code

Comment: You need to create DisplayMessageActivity.java in same package

Comment: Mahesh - added manifest as requested

Comment: talhakosen - I can see that I can simply manually add the class, but I would like Eclipse to do it for me as I went through the New Activity wizard. Maybe I have set something up incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

The fastest solution: keep the Activity in your manifest, but create the java class by right-clicking your package -> new -> class -> DisplayMessageActivity and then extend the Activity class and add the missing methods. Note that the class name have to match the one declared in the manifest

**EDIT**
After you've done it, clean the project by selecting project -> clean and check if there are any error messages left

Comment: Thank you Maver1ck - this is what I'm going to do, however, I'd like to know why the class wasn't automatically created for me. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: I can't say it for sure since I never use graphical interfaces to create java classes or edit the manifest file but I suppose you missed something. My (subjective) suggestion is to manually create new classes since you can be sure that no errors occur

Answer (score 1):

I needed to uninstall Eclipse and install the sdk (adt bundle) from http://developer.android.com/ which comes bundled with eclipse to resolve this issue.

I found that my original set-up not only failed to create source files, but was also unable to create new android projects, even though it managed to create the first project successfully. Something must have happened to ruin the set up, no doubt, something I did but cannot trace.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me... 
In eclipse, go to **Help** >
**Install new software...** > Work with: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Hit enter, checkmark "*Developer Tools*" and "*NDK Plugins*".

Let it download and install. I had to delete "myfirstapp" and remake it. 
Restart Eclipse once it has downloaded and installed.

Having that issue and actually doing it over again helped me understand more about the syntax used in the lessons that I've already been through before.